# How to add css file in component in Next js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I created project in Next js. I have components. But I want to add CSS file using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />` in components.

I wrote this code but page could not found. How can I solve this ?

My code

```
const Header = () => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Head>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"
          />
          <title>Site | Title</title>
          <link href="/statics/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </Head>
      </Fragment>
    );
}
```

Thank you best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js is a React framework so just do it like you would with React. If you are using external css file just import it at the top of the file. Then if you have class Foo inside app.css eg.

```css
.Foo {
    color: blue;
}
```

```js
import '/statics/app.css';

const Header = () => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Head>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"
          />
          <title>Site | Title</title>
        </Head>
       <>
         <p className="Foo">Bar</p>
       </>
      </Fragment>
    );
}
```

If you want to define styles globally like themes for the whole app do this in your `pages/_app.js` file. Resource: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But  when i use it this way import '/statics/app.css'; css is not working.

Comment: Are you sure that the path to the css file is correct?